# Running Custom Deployer from Eclipse

Tags: tridion

I've gone through [Jaime's deployer tutorial](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_1.aspx).

I've successfully created my deployer extension, which when integrating with SDL Tridion, the functionality works exactly as required.

But, what i can't get to work is the local debugging / running with the deployer inside eclipse (documented [here](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_7.aspx))

The eclipse based deployer does run.  If I drop my zip file into my test incoming folder the zip is picked up and processed.  However, the customdeployer code I have written is never entered or executed.

I don't get any errors in the 'eclipse' deployer logs, but it always stops on the following line:

> 2012-04-13 20:24:51,642 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removing exclusive lock on Deployment package: tcm:0-1026-66560 with type: CONTENT.

As we've three developers here also stuck on the same problem on all their machines I was wondering (hoping!) that this was a common problem and someone knew what we're doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Did you were to resolve your issue? is there any sample code where deployer is written for PageDeploy or Undeploy, as I am also looking to create one extension on page publish and unpublish, which will create .txt file on server in format 123456.txt where 123456 will be pageid of the published page, I have got this documentation (http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_3.aspx) it just a basic setup, can you suggest where we can get any other good sample to create custom deployer with local debugging ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check which `cd_deployer_conf.xml` is it loaded by the Deployer? Just check the Deployer startup logs (in debug mode).

I suspect your Eclipse project at Debug/Run time doesn't load the the `cd_*_config.xml` files from the `config` folder in Eclipse. This will prevent your deployer module (which I supposed you configured in your `cd_deployer_conf.xml`) from being loaded and called.

What I normally do is to declare this `config` folder as an Eclipse *Source Folder*. Then at Debug/Run time, Eclipse will be included in the classpath automatically. This makes point #8 from http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_3.aspx redundant.

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thanks for the answer, I'm investigating.  That said I do see this in my logs so I know it's getting the details from the correct place: 2012-04-13 17:58:14,743 INFO  Deployer - Using configuration: file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ExampleDeloyerExtension/config/cd_deployer_conf.xml

I also see the class name picked up, but it just never enters my extension.

Comment: What module is it? Maybe you are not publishing that particular item type in your publish/unpublish transaction. Can you post more info? maybe code sample of your method. Logs? Is the extension class being instantiated in the logs?

Comment: Do you have a cd_license.xml in the project as well?

Comment: Yes, I have a cd_license.xml in there.  It is actually deploying the zip, just ignoring the extension.  I've tried the same zip in my actual deployer, and the custom code is ran

Comment: Hi Mihai, not yet I'm going to look at it this morning

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem after following the same deployer extension tutorial.

I managed to solve it by changing the name of the package that my module was in to be com.tridion.deployer.extensions

Previously my module had been in a package I had named com.yourcompany.tridion.deployer.extensions and this appeared to have the affect of preventing the deployer from loading my extension module.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, with a slight variation in that originally it worked, but then it stopped working. 
Turns out the deployment package was somehow getting corrupted(locked?) in the process, as when i tried with a backup of the deployment package from the previous day it worked just fine.