# prototype or approach for having a Deployer Extension in Java for SDL Tridion 2011 for indexing of content into Apache Solr

Tags: java, solr, tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Can any one help me in supplying a prototype or approach for a Deployer Extension in Java for SDL Tridion 2011, so that this app/process/module can consume the delta publish and index that content into Apache Solr?

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion community on Stack Overflow Rajesh. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a community based Question and Answer site. We're usually quite willing to help people who are stuck on a concrete problem, but it is important that you tell us what ***you***'ve already tried. Open questions like the one you asked here, tend to upset people and leave a (probably false) impression that you might be trying to get us to do your work. I recommend reading this article: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Hi Bart Koopman,
sorry for the not being specific in my question here.
i am working on a desing approach of integrating SDL tridion 2011 with redesigned websites powered with apache solr
For this I have been going through the documentation @ SDL and below URL tutorial some info. 
http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer_extensions_with_eclipse_1.aspx
But this does not specify how the published document can be consumed in other java process.
I will share the design approach here once i have it ready or come up with more specific question if any.
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at these other questions on SO:

[How can we override the existing deployer customization in Tridion 2009?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773585/how-can-we-override-the-existing-deployer-customization-in-tridion-2009)

[Running Custom Deployer from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146490/running-custom-deployer-from-eclipse)

[How to make a Custom Deployer to write data to MS SQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361594/how-to-make-a-custom-deployer-to-write-data-to-ms-sql-database)

[Need to get the XML of a component's that version which is published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614756/need-to-get-the-xml-of-a-components-that-version-which-is-published)

[How can we integrate Microsoft FAST with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014950/how-can-we-integrate-microsoft-fast-with-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1)

The last one specifically deals with updating a search collection. If this does not help, please show us what you have tried with some code samples.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for updating late on this post.
Now we have a working deployer which extracts the required information and indexes the published content to Apche solr.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for updating late on this post.  Now we have a working deployer which extracts the required information and indexes the published content to Apche solr.  <br/>What we have done is:  
1)Added new module tag in cd_deployer_conf.xml (configuration file in cd_deployer.war that comes with SDL 2011 product) as<Module Type="SolrPageDeploy"Class="com.reliant.tridion.extention.IndexPageToSolr">
...... </module>. This IndexPageToSolr has processPage(Page page, File pageFile) method which is called each time a page is published from SDL (we are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1).

Comment: So is your issue solved? If so please vote for and accept the answer. Or better still, if you have code you can share, please post it as your own answer and accept it in order to help others.

Comment: Running Custom Deployer from Eclipse<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146490/running-custom-deployer-from-eclipse> answer helped me in getting to some point on my final solution.
And the SDL Live tutorial here<http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_1.aspx>
helped me getting to my final solution.

Answer (score 1):

SDL tridion 2011 SP1 Deployer comes as a war file (here we have as cd_deplyer.war) which can be deployed in any appserver, this is the place where we can have custom code to extend the deployer to have our custom logic to be applied to published content from SDL.
This war file will have many config files one of them is cd_deployer_conf.xml where we have to declare a module tag which gets called for each time content is published.
for Ex:   
    .
    .
     
    .......
    .
Similarly for undeploy

```
<Processor Action="Undeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
.
<Module Type="SolrPageUndeploy" Class="com.xyz.RemovePageFromSolr">
.
.
```

These IndexPageToSolr and RemovePageFromSolr will get required metadata for indexing to solr and unindexing from solr.
We can have our java classes in the same war file or we can have all of the war files in our war file and deploy in any appserver and give the app full context path to SDL for publishing.